Image base path not taking in sass
we are using sass nowadays. here when we tried to add src img path like "/us/products/sites/default/files/2024-05/error-invalid_3.png" which is in dam not taking getting error in map.js file
//asset path
$assetPath : url(/us/products/sites/default/files/2024-05/error-invalid_3.png;)
if we give path like this it should take but now we are uploading in local theme folder like below
//asset path
$assetPath : url(../images/error-invalid.png);
